# sibling taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks

Drupal 7

I have a vocabulary with hierarchical terms countries and cities.

I have a view with context filter=cityA ( parent country A)

How I can display into a block all cities from country A  ( siblings of cityA from vocabulary)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `taxonomy_get_children($termid)` to get children of term and then `taxonomy_get_parents($termid)` and again `taxonomy_get_children()` to get the siblings . 
The following is the code I used in such situation :

```
<?php

if (isset($page['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui']['view']->args[0])){
    $termid = $page['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui']['view']->args[0];
    $terms = taxonomy_get_children($termid);

    if (empty($terms)) {
        $parent = taxonomy_get_parents($termid);
        $terms = taxonomy_get_children(key($parent));
    }
}

if (isset($node->field_category['und'][0]['tid'])) {
    $termid =  $node->field_category['und'][0]['tid'];
    $terms = taxonomy_get_children($termid);
}

?>
```

Comment: Where specified vocabulary?

Comment: we generalise the taxonomy terms in $terms and $termid .

Comment: Do not know why isset($page['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui']['view']->args[0])) return False in this page site.com/view/cityA

Comment: Could you please paste the code you are using ? and which file you are using this code in ?

Comment: I used the code above, in a block. I have a view with 1 contextual filters(arguments) site.com/view/city